# Unicode with Jinja2 on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode, jinja2

I have a lib/languages.py file only with a dict format e.g.:

```
en = {}
en["farewell"] = "goddbye"
es = {}
es["farewell"] = "Adi&oacute;s"
```

Also I have a lib/basehandler.py where I use language.py and this basehandler has a Unicode literal (**# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-**)

The problem is that when I render a template in Spanish (es), the html has "Adi&ocuate;s" instead "Adi&oaucte;s"

I tried to use on languages.py

```
es["farewell"] = "Adi&oacute;s"
```

or add Unicode literal (**# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-**), but nothing work.

Can anyone please, tell me what I'm doing wrong or what's the best way to work with Unicode on Jinja2

Here is the source code https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate and if you want to see the problem http://appengine.protoboard.cl/?&hl=es

Thanks in advance

Comment: `"&oacute;"` is not a unicode literal, it's an HTML entity that's expressed entirely in ASCII characters. The python interpreter doesn't need to be told the source encoding to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library you're using of jinja2 has autoescape default set to True. You may override this in your code by going to `basehandler.py`, and look for these lines:

```
@webapp2.cached_property
def jinja2(self):
    return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)
```

Replace it with this:

```
@webapp2.cached_property
def jinja2(self):
    return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app,{'environment_args':{'autoescape':False}})
```

I'm not sure if `environment_args` and `autoescape` in the additional code above need the single quotes or not. Feel free to try different variations of them.

If you want to keep `autoescape True` as the default, then you can just add `|safe` to each variable in your template.

For example in `home.html`

```
{{ lang.text_title }}
```

becomes

```
{{ lang.text_title|safe }}
```

and so on...

Comment: thanks, now the [boilerplate](http://appengine.protoboard.cl) even supports Chinese :D

Comment: Cool! Just curious. Which method above did you end up using? Setting the autoescape default to False or adding |safe to the template?

Comment: I would **strongly discourage** touching `autoescape`: anywhere you are printing user input without escaping, you have an HTML-injection vulnerability, likely leading to cross-site scripting.

Comment: PS. looking at your code you seem to be marking form `action`s as `|safe`. Why? They are not safe and need HTML-escaping like anything else.

Answer (score 3):

```
es["farewell"] = "Adi&oacute;s"
```

You shouldn't need to use HTML markup to get non-ASCII characters. Use a Python Unicode string literal:

```
es["farewell"] = u"Adi\u00F3s"
```

Or, if you've got your `coding` directive and text editor encoding lined up correctly, just:

```
es["farewell"] = u"Adiós"
```

The problem with including HTML in strings is that you then have to output it without HTML-escaping, at which point any `<` or `&` characters in the string break, and if there's any user input added to the string you've got a security problem. Better to keep strings in raw unescaped form until the moment they hit output.

Comment: @coto this is the better answer. :)